# Pandas DataFrame creation throws ValueError in loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a nested dictionary(stats), which I'm trying to convert into a Pandas DF. When I run the below code, I get the desired result:

```
BAL_sp = pd.DataFrame(data = stats['sp']['Orioles'])
```

However, I need to do this 30 times then concatenate the results. When I run a for loop, I get a `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` I don't understand, it is recognizing the key in stats as valid in the loop:

```
team_dict = {'LAA': 'Angels', 'ARI': 'Diamondbacks', 'BAL': 'Orioles', 'BOS': 'Red Sox', 'CHC': 'Cubs', 'CIN': 'Reds', 
      'CLE': 'Indians', 'COL': 'Rockies', 'DET': 'Tigers', 'HOU': 'Astros', 'KC': 'Royals', 'LAD': 'Dodgers', 
      'WSH':'Nationals', 'NYM': 'Mets', 'OAK': 'Athletics', 'PIT': 'Pirates', 'SD': 'Padres', 'SEA': 'Mariners', 
      'SF': 'Giants', 'STL': 'Cardinals', 'TB': 'Rays', 'TEX': 'Rangers', 'TOR': 'Blue Jays', 'MIN': 'Twins', 
      'PHI': 'Phillies', 'ATL': 'Braves', 'CWS': 'White Sox', 'MIA': 'Marlins', 'NYY': 'Yankees', 'MIL': 'Brewers' }


frames = []
for team in team_dict.values():
    temp = pd.DataFrame(data = stats['sp'][team])
    frames.append(temp)
sp_df = pd.concat(frames)
```

It doesn't throw an error if I do `data = [stats['sp'][team]]`, but that does not produce the desired result. Thank you for any help.

Comment: There are no objects called `stats`. `NameError: name 'stats' is not defined`

Comment: stats is a nested dictionary of my own. The first line of code creates the desired data frame. All of the values in team_dict are keys in stats['sp'], such as 'Orioles', which works when I do it individually. Why does it not work when looping?Thanks for any help.

Comment: Without a representative example of the data, it's difficult to provide a solution.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney What I'm asking is why df = pd.DataFrame(data = stats['sp']['Angels']) works fine, but when looping through team_dict.values() (the first iteration being 'Angels') does not work.

Comment: How can anyone answer the question without `stats` and knowing what the expected output is? The question needs to include enough information to answer the question and currently it does not.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney  I thought because when I do each iteration of the loop individually, I get the desired result, someone could tell me why inserting each key in the loop is different.

Comment: The problem is that DataFrame's data parameter takes a dict(can contain list/series), array or dataframe as an input, whereas you are providing a string value 'team'. You won't get an error if you pass a list([item]) or series(pd.Series(item)) in the data parameter.

Comment: can you post your `stats` dictionary here?

Comment: I appreciate it, but still don't understand. stats['sp'][team] represents 30 dictionaries. What is different about my first line of code (which works) and stats['sp'][team] if team == to 'Orioles'? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Without an example of what's in `stats` this is only a guess... but are you sure `stats['sp']` contains a similar structure for all the values in `team_dict`? Not all dictionaries are automatically loadable to pandas.

Comment: Hi, everyone. You were all right in that you needed to see stats, because I had loaded the dictionary in a pickle file and accidentally edited one of the branches. When I reloaded the cell in Jupyter it worked. So, the question is garbage because the looping is exactly the same. Thanks all for your time.